# How to have getter and setter of different data type

Tags: c#, enums

If I need to convert the below code to set using ResponseStatus input and give a getter with string in one property with as give below public string ResponseStatus {get; set;}

```
    private string _responseStatus;

    public string GetResponseStatus()
    {
        return _responseStatus.ToString();
    }

    public void SetResponseStatus(ResponseStatus responseStatus)
    {
        _responseStatus = responseStatus.ToString();
    }
```

Need to update the following as above,

```
public string ResponseStatus { 
        get { 
            return _responseStatus; 
        } 
        set { **// Need to check for the "ReponseStatus" type before setting this**
           _responseStatus = value.ToString(); } 
    }
```

But I need to make sure that value ResponseStatus is only set with the value of type "ResponseStatus"

```
public enum ResponseStatus
{
    Failed = 0,
    Success = 1,
    PartialSuccess = 2
}
```

Comment: Why not just make the entire property of type `ResponseStatus`? Why do you want this "asymmetry" of the getter and setter?

Comment: @Sweeper I want the response to be shared as "String" for the property and not as Enum to the client. If would be easy for the client to read if it says "Failed / Success" in the response rather than "0/1/2"

Comment: But the client is a computer program..? Anyway, if this is Json serialization you can make the serialiser send and receive string enums instead of numbers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can't have a property with two different types, but you can use the `value object` concept to achieve what you need here.

for example, I assume you want to have a DTO class like this

```cs
public class TestDto
{
    public string ResponseStatus { get; set; } 
}

public enum ResponseStatuses
{
    Failed = 0,
    Success = 1,
    PartialSuccess = 2
}
```

that your setter should be an Enum and your getter should return string.
to achieve that you can define a value object type.

```cs
// value object type example
public record ResponseStatus 
{
    private string _responseStatus;
    public ResponseStatus(ResponseStatuses responseStatus)
    {
        _responseStatus = responseStatus.ToString();    
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _responseStatus;
    }
    public static implicit operator ResponseStatus(ResponseStatuses value)
    {
        return new ResponseStatus(value);
    }
}
```

and use this in your DTO instead

```cs
public class TestDto
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus {get; set;} // this always return string to the client
}
```

---

usage example :

```cs
   var testResult = new TestDto();
   testResult.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatuses.Success;
   
   Console.WriteLine(testResult.ResponseStatus); // it is string "Success"
```

Note: in this example, I used a `record` to define a value object but if you are not using the latest c# versions there are [other ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects) to create a value object